# PHP, jQuery, Ajax, send HTML input fields with attachment field code not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send an email with an optional attachment when a button is clicked and display the results above the form fields. I have put together the following code, but it is not working (nothing happens when I click the submit button; would like to create a fiddle but JSFiddle does not accept PHP code):

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div id="contactSubmitResult"></div>
      <div id="contactSubmitResult"></div>
      <div id="contactForm">
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_firstname">Firstname <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="form_firstname" name="form_firstname" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_lastname">Lastname <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="form_lastname" name="form_lastname" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="form_address" name="form_address" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_city">City</label>
          <input type="text" id="form_city" name="form_city" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form_email" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="tel" id="form_phone" name="form_phone" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <label for="form_attachment">Add Attachment</label>
          <input type="file" id="form_attachment" name="form_attachment" />
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <label for="form_message">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <input type="submit" id="form_send" value="Send" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jdoe.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- validate and submit form input -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    matchFormFields = "#contactForm input[required], #contactForm textarea[required]";

    matchContactSubmitResult = "#contactSubmitResult";

    errorColor = 'red';

    $("#form_send").click(function() { 

      var formIsValid = true;

      // loop through each field and change border color to red for invalid fields       

      $(matchFormFields).each(function() {

        $(this).css('border-color', '');

        // check whether field is empty

        if(!$.trim($(this).val())) {

          $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);

          formIsValid = false;

        }

        // check whether email is valid

        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 

        if($(this).attr("type") == "email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {

          $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);

          formIsValid = false;

        }   

      });

      // submit data to server if form field contents are valid

      if (formIsValid) {

        // retrieve input field values to be sent to server

        var post_data = new FormData();
        post_data.append('form_firstname',  $('input[name=form_firstname]').val());
        post_data.append('form_lastname',   $('input[name=form_lastname]').val());
        post_data.append('form_address',    $('input[name=form_address]').val());
        post_data.append('form_city',       $('input[name=form_city]').val());
        post_data.append('form_email',      $('input[name=form_email]').val());
        post_data.append('form_phone',      $('input[name=form_phone]').val());
        post_data.append('form_attachment', $('input[name=form_attachment]')[0].files[0]);
        post_data.append('form_message',    $('textarea[name=form_message]').val());

        // Ajax post data to server

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://jdoe.com/sendContactFormEmail.php',
          data: post_data,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {  

            if (response.type == 'error') { // load json data from server and output message

              output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';

            } else {

              output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';

              // reset values in all form fields

              $(matchFormFields).val('');

            }

            // display an animation with the form submission results

            $(matchContactSubmitResult).hide().html(output).slideDown();

          }

        });

      }

    });

    // reset border on entering characters in form fields

    $(matchFormFields).keyup(function() {

      $(this).css('border-color', '');

      $(matchContactSubmitResult).slideUp();

    });

  });

    </script>
```

Here is the PHP code which receives the jQuery AJAX POST request:

```
<?php

      //$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Yes'));

      //die($output);

  include("settings.php");

  $boundaryString = "generateboundaryfromthis";

  $to_email = "jdoe@gmail.com";

  $from_email = "noreply@jdoe.com";

  $replyTo_email = "noreply@jdoe.com";

  if (isset($_POST)) {

    // check whether this is an ajax request, exit if not

    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

      $output = json_encode(array(
        'type' =>' error', 
        'text' => 'Ajax POST request expected.'
      ));

      die($output); //exit script outputting json data

    } 

    // retrieve sanitized input data

    $form_firstname  = filter_var($_POST["form_firstname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $form_lastname   = filter_var($_POST["form_lastname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $form_address    = filter_var($_POST["form_address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $form_city       = filter_var($_POST["form_city"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $form_email      = filter_var($_POST["form_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $form_phone      = filter_var($_POST["form_phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $form_message    = filter_var($_POST["form_message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $email_body = <<<EOT
Firstname: $form_firstname
Lastname: $form_lastname
Address: $form_address
City: $form_city
E-mail: $form_email
Phone: $form_phone
Message:
$form_message
EOT;

    // retrieve attached file

    $hasAttachment = false;

    if (isset($_FILES["form_attachment"])) {

      $hasAttachment = true;

      $fileTmpName = $_FILES["form_attachment"]['tmp_name'];
      $fileName    = $_FILES["form_attachment"]['name'];
      $fileSize    = $_FILES["form_attachment"]['size'];
      $fileType    = $_FILES["form_attachment"]['type'];
      $fileError   = $_FILES["form_attachment"]['error'];

      $handle = fopen($fileTmpName);

      $content = fread($handle, $fileSize);

      fclose($handle);

      $encodedContent = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    }

    if ($hasAttachment) {

      // user submitted an attachment

      $boundary = md5($boundaryString);

      // header

      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
      $headers .= "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n"; 
      $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $replyTo_email . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

      // plain text 

      $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
      $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
      $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($email_body)); 

      // attachment

      $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
      $body .="Content-Type: $fileType; name=\"$fileName\"\r\n";
      $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"\r\n";
      $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
      $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
      $body .= $encodedContent; 

    } else {

      // user did not submit an attachment

      $headers = "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n" .
                 "Reply-To: " . $replyTo_email . "\n" .
                 "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

      $body = $email_body;

    }

    $mailSentSuccessfully = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);

    if ($mailSentSuccessfully) {

      //$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => $pageSettings->getContents("mailSentSuccess")));
      $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Message sent.'));

      die($output);

    } else {

      //$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $pageSettings->getContents("mailSentFailure")));
      $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Error encountered. Message not sent.'));

      die($output);

    }

  }
```

Comment: Since I am using jQuery with AJAX to do the post, there is no <form>, but there is an enclosing <div> instead. I've seen this done on the web, it should be valid HTML. I am not submitting old-style. I am submitting dynamically with jQuery.

Comment: My code was working in an enclosing <div> before I added the code for the attachment, so I'm not sure where the problem is. Is there a place on the net where I can run and debug this code? If I use <form> then clicking on <submit> will refresh the page.

Comment: @Teemu it's ajax, nothing to do with forms!

Comment: @Teemu He is taking the values with javascript and sending them with ajax to php script!

Comment: @MozzieMD, any idea where the problem in the code is and how I can debug it?

Comment: _“Is there a place on the net where I can run and debug this code?”_ – yes, and that place is called _your browser_. Use the developer tools to debug your script, maybe even step through it, and use the network panel to see what request is made (if any.) After you have done that, and ensured everything is working properly on the client side (by comparing the request to the one that a normal form, submitted the “tradiditional” way, would create), you can move on to the server side and debug things there (if that will still be necessary by then.)

Answer (score 2):

One problem: you forgot to put a html tag to

```
matchContactSubmitResult = "#contactSubmitResult";
```

add

```
<div id="contactSubmitResult"></div>
```

Here is snippet. I take the liberty to provide an alternative to `success: function(){}`, instead I used `.done()` and `.fail()` to provide in network or other problems. See here: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (I can't test your php code, but your jquery code works)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    matchFormFields = "#contactForm input[required], #contactForm textarea[required]";

    matchContactSubmitResult = "#contactSubmitResult";

    errorColor = 'red';

    $("#form_send").click(function() { 

      var formIsValid = true;

      // loop through each field and change border color to red for invalid fields       

      $(matchFormFields).each(function() {

        $(this).css('border-color', '');

        // check whether field is empty

        if(!$.trim($(this).val())) {

          $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);

          formIsValid = false;

        }

        // check whether email is valid

        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 

        if($(this).attr("type") == "email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {

          $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);

          formIsValid = false;

        }   

      });

      // submit data to server if form field contents are valid

      if (formIsValid) {

        // retrieve input field values to be sent to server

        var post_data = new FormData();
        post_data.append('form_firstname',  $('input[name=form_firstname]').val());
        post_data.append('form_lastname',   $('input[name=form_lastname]').val());
        post_data.append('form_address',    $('input[name=form_address]').val());
        post_data.append('form_city',       $('input[name=form_city]').val());
        post_data.append('form_email',      $('input[name=form_email]').val());
        post_data.append('form_phone',      $('input[name=form_phone]').val());
        post_data.append('form_attachment', $('input[name=form_attachment]')[0].files[0]);
        post_data.append('form_message',    $('textarea[name=form_message]').val());

        // Ajax post data to server

        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://jdoe.com/sendContactFormEmail.php',
          data: post_data,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json'

        }) .done(function(response) {  

            if (response.type == 'error') { // load json data from server and output message

            output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';

            } else {

              output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';

              // reset values in all form fields

              $(matchFormFields).val('');

            }
$(matchContactSubmitResult).hide().html(output).slideDown();


          }).
          fail( function(response){
              output = '<div class="error"> NetWork Problems</div>';
          $(matchContactSubmitResult).hide().html(output).slideDown();

            });
        
      }

    });

    // reset border on entering characters in form fields

    $(matchFormFields).keyup(function() {

      $(this).css('border-color', '');

      $(matchContactSubmitResult).slideUp();

    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactForm">
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_firstname">Firstname <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="form_firstname" name="form_firstname" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_lastname">Lastname <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" id="form_lastname" name="form_lastname" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="form_address" name="form_address" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_city">City</label>
          <input type="text" id="form_city" name="form_city" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
          <label for="form_email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form_email" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <label for="form_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input type="tel" id="form_phone" name="form_phone" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <label for="form_attachment">Add Attachment</label>
          <input type="file" id="form_attachment" name="form_attachment" />
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <label for="form_message">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col12">
          <input type="submit" id="form_send" value="Send" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
        </div>
      </div>
<div id="contactSubmitResult"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting use of .done() and .fail(). However I woldn't use .fail() in production code. Thanks for the testing. However, it's not my jQuery code which is not working but my PHP code. Any idea where the problem with the PHP code is?

Comment: I've updated my code. There are no errors with the PHP code but when I try to attach an attachment nothing happens.

Comment: I have looked at your PHP code and it could be your problem there. Coupe of things to check; have you looked in your php log? Can you write temps files? Have you use `var_dump()` to debug the php code? you should try it in localhost and output the raw return of php instead of `json` of even better, use Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox Dev Tools and see what the ajax return.

Answer (score 0):

> I've updated my code. There are no errors with the PHP code but when I
>   try to attach an attachment nothing happens. –  [John Sonderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610873/john-sonderson)

if so i think the problem is here.haven't tested but, this might help :)

```
var myfile=$('input[name=form_attachment]').val();
//apend the file
post_data.append('form_attachment', myfile);
```